# NSSwap returning a signed integer?

Tags: objective-c, ios, endianness

I'm trying to swap the bytes of a 32 bit unsigned integer using NSSwap

my original NSInteger is **13a81fbe** and I'd like it to become: **be1fa813**

after running

```
NSInteger swappedInteger = NSSwapInt(unencodedInteger);
```

I get a new integer whos byte values are: **be1fa813**. But when I go to print this to the console, i get -1105221613

my full code is this:

```
//get bytes within range
NSInteger unencodedInteger;
[mydata getBytes:&unencodedInteger range:myRange];

//swap the endianess of the bytes
NSInteger swappedInteger = NSSwapInt(unencodedInteger);

//debug logging
NSLog(@"Original: %x (%d)   Swapped: %x (%d)",unencodedInteger, unencodedInteger,swappedInteger, swappedInteger);

//add swapped integer to array
[banks addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:swappedInteger]];
```

Does anyone understand why the new swapped value is acting as if it's signed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In binary:

```
0xbe1fa813 = 0b10111110000111111010100000010011
```

Now presumably the architecture you're working with (iOS) treats signed integers as if they're represented in 2-complement. I. e., the most significant bit is set when the value is negative. So this number, interpreted as a signed integer, is negative, since it begins by a `1` bit. I just made a quick test program on OS X and indeed `printf()` prints a nice negative and positive integer, depending upon what conversion specifier I supply:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%x %u %d\n", 0xbe1fa813, (unsigned)0xbe1fa813, 0xbe1fa813);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
be1fa813 3189745683 -1105221613
```

I'd say that all this is **definitely expected.**

Comment: you're right. by printing the NSInteger using %u instead of %d, I do in fact see that my integer was swapped correctly

Comment: @shred444 Yep, that's it pretty much. Don't forget the cast to (unsigned), however, if you feed a signed value to an unsigned conversion specifier, that results in undefined behavior, that's why I cast it in my code as well.

Answer (score 0):

`%d` in `printf` will interpret an integer as signed. Use `%u` if you like to interpret it as unsigned.